# How to use library from miniconda in default python2.7 in Mac?

Tags: python, pandas, pip, miniconda

For some project I need to use `/usr/bin/python` with version 2.7.
I could not install `pandas` library due to SSL problems.

However, I already have pandas installed in `miniconda`.

Can we use `pandas` from `miniconda` to the default python?

**My attempt**

```
/usr/bin/python --version # Python 2.7.10

ls ~/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas # it has __init__.py etc.

/usr/local/bin/pip --version # pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

/usr/local/bin/pip install pandas # THIS FAILS
```

**Attempt 2**

```
# File a.py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/Users/poudel/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/")

import pandas # this fails


# another try

sys.path.append("/Users/poudel/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/")

import pandas # This also fails
```

How can I use pandas from minconda (or anywhere local) to default python on Mac ?

**Update for @darthbith **
Here is the screenshot for Alfred Workflow:
There is no option to choose another python version.

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to use the system Python? What is wrong with the Conda Python 2.7?

Comment: @darthbith, I was writing an Alfred workflow (MacOS productivity app), and that software only allows to use builtin python, and anaconda or anything else.

Comment: I don't see anything on the README that says you must use the system Python. Can you point out where it says that? I'm asking because I don't think you can do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Alright... well, what is this mysterious SSL error you've received when you try to install pandas for the system Python? Why are you using `/usr/local/bin/pip` to try to install for `/usr/bin/python`? There are a lot of details missing here...